# Catching URLs opened on website via python

Tags: python, url

I want to form a service that can automatically take url(that I open) from my web browser and send it to some program that I have written. How is it possible? I have no idea what is it called and what will it require.

I have a webservice written in Flask that is taking all these urls and sending it to beanstalk queue. I will be taking these urls and call the service to push urls to beanstalk.

Comment: This is a broad question that does not have one clear answer. Could be a browser extension, proxy... you need to do some research/design work.

Comment: Can you give me some keywords that I could google?

Comment: You want a way to listen in on your webbrowser and extract all urls from the pages it fetches? And you want to do it with python? Forget it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is install http://mitmproxy.org/, then set your operating system to use it as the system wide http/https proxy. Then any HTTP requests that the web browser makes will go through it, you can easily write plugins for mitmproxy and inspect transactions.

Comment: I think you will have a lot of 'noise' urls too, such as image, css, javascript urls etc.

Comment: Can I use web browser directly to copy urls and give that to me?

Comment: That'd be the wrong and hardest way to do it (i.e. modify the source of the browser and compile a custom version). But, it is possible.